# GraphQL refetchQueries after mutation, this.props not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

This problem makes no sense to me at all... I am adding an author to a database using a mutation like this:

```
this.props
      .addAuthorMutation({
        variables: {
          name: this.state.name,
          age: this.state.age
        },
        refetchQueries: [
          {
            query: getAuthorsQuery,
            variables: {
              awaitRefetchQueries: true
            }
          }
        ]
      })
      .then(() => this.submitBookAlso());
```

Then simply...

```
  submitBookAlso() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.props);
  }
```

For some mysterious reason, when I inspect (this) in the console, this.props.getAuthorsQuery.authors contains my added author, however, (this.props) in the console does not. The new author is added to a dropdown in another component successfully, and is in the database, but I cannot seem to get the author after the mutation. I would like to filter it...

```
let author = this.props.getAuthorsQuery.authors.filter(
  author => this.state.name === author.name
);
console.log(author);
```

...but this just gives me an empty array. What I am wanting to do is trigger another mutation when that one is finished (adding a book to a separate database collection with the new added author as it's author).

I get the same result without using awaitRefetchQueries, and also using onCompleted instead of .then(). These are my current dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.16",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-apollo": "^2.2.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.3"
  },
```

Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: So this looks to be a problem with the design of Apollo and the refetchQueries method not waiting to finish before running .then()... Apparently this is by design and would be a breaking chain to change it. In the meantime it works to simply chain promises like so.............                         

`this.props.myMutation( { variables: { myVariables } } )
.then( () => this.props.myQuery.refetch() )
.then( data => data.data.newQueryDataShouleBeUpdated )`

Answer (score 4):

Try passing `awaitRefetchQueries` in directly to the mutation and not nested inside of `refetchQueries` like this:

```
this.props
      .addAuthorMutation({
        variables: {
          name: this.state.name,
          age: this.state.age
        },
        awaitRefetchQueries: true,
        refetchQueries: [
          {
            query: getAuthorsQuery
          }
        ]
      })
      .then(() => this.submitBookAlso());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I haven't touched this project since 2018 so I was never able to test your solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

// Pass Refetch when declaring useQuery example in hooks

```
const {data, error, loading, refetch} = useQuery("Your query")

const [addAuthorMutation] = useMutation("Your Mutation",{
variables: { "your variables"},
onCompleted: (data) => { "dispatch your action creators"},
refetch()

})
```